# How to sum columns by unique row values while collapsing other columns?

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, lapply, rowsum

I have a data set with sales numbers from individual items ordered on various dates. All items in a particular order share the same ID. I want to calculate order totals (i.e. sum of sales for all items in a particular order), while preserving the date associated with each order (we can assume all items part of an order share the same date). How do I sum sales with respect to ID, while preserving the date?

This questions is different from others I've seen, because I want to preserve and collapse the Date column while summing with respect to a different column, Sales.

Columns before: `Date`, `ID`, `Sales`

Columns after: `Date`, `ID`, `Order.Total`

The following code returns an error because dates obviously cannot be summed :

```
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "ID"]
```

The following code removes the Date field altogether :

```
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "ID", .SDcols = !"Date"]
```

For example, if my data set before is :

```
DATE  ID  SALES
1/2   01    1 
1/2   01    2
1/2   02    3
1/3   03    6
1/4   04    5
1/4   04    4
```

My data set after should be :

```
DATE  ID  ORDER.TOTAL
1/2   01    3 
1/2   02    3
1/3   03    6
1/4   04    9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're after this?

```
dt[, .(ORDER.TOTAL = sum(SALES)), by =.(DATE, ID)]
#    DATE ID ORDER.TOTAL
#1:  1/2  1           3
#2:  1/2  2           3
#3:  1/3  3           6
#4:  1/4  4           9
```

which is the same as

```
dt[, list(ORDER.TOTAL = sum(SALES)), by = list(DATE, ID)]
```

Or the same in base R using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(SALES ~ DATE + ID, data = as.data.frame(dt), FUN = sum)
#  DATE ID SALES
#1  1/2  1     3
#2  1/2  2     3
#3  1/3  3     6
#4  1/4  4     9
```

---

### Sample data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("DATE  ID  SALES
1/2   01    1
1/2   01    2
1/2   02    3
1/3   03    6
1/4   04    5
1/4   04    4")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Update: First method ended up taking 2 mins to run on a data set with ~500,000 rows, but the aggregate function worked in seconds. Thanks for providing both options.